# How to adjust the xand y axis line in jfreecharts

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

In my jfree line chart the x and y axis line is drawn seperated.. I need to get both the axis meet at the orgin. 
Here is the Actual Image im getting from jfree line chart
[image]

How to join the two axis line at the orgin in jfree line chart...

I've tried by using this code sample

```
final DefaultCategoryDataset lineDataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        lineDataset.addValue(10, "Dep", "2009");
        lineDataset.addValue(11, "Dep", "2010");
        lineDataset.addValue(10, "Dep", "2011");
        lineDataset.addValue(10, "Dep", "2012");

        lineDataset.addValue(7, "Dia", "2009");
        lineDataset.addValue(7, "Dia", "2010");
        lineDataset.addValue(7, "Dia", "2011");
        lineDataset.addValue(7, "Dia", "2012");

        lineDataset.addValue(3, "HD", "2009");
        lineDataset.addValue(3, "HD", "2010");
        lineDataset.addValue(3, "HD", "2011");
        lineDataset.addValue(3, "HD", "2012");

        lineDataset.addValue(16, "HBP", "2009");
        lineDataset.addValue(15, "HBP", "2010");
        lineDataset.addValue(18, "HBP", "2011");
        lineDataset.addValue(17, "HBP", "2012");

        lineDataset.addValue(16, "HC", "2009");
        lineDataset.addValue(15, "HC", "2010");
        lineDataset.addValue(16, "HC", "2011");
        lineDataset.addValue(16, "HC", "2012");

        lineDataset.addValue(6, "LBP", "2009");
        lineDataset.addValue(7, "LBP", "2010");
        lineDataset.addValue(6, "LBP", "2011");
        lineDataset.addValue(6, "LBP", "2012");

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "", // chart title
                "", // domain axis label
                "", // range axis label
                lineDataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                false, // include legend
                false, // tooltips
                false // urls
        );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        final CategoryAxis categoryAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        categoryAxis.setAxisLineVisible(true);
        categoryAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
        categoryAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2);
        categoryAxis.setLowerMargin(-0.1);

        categoryAxis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.decode("#222222"));
        chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, -8, 0, 0));

//        categoryAxis.setTickLabelFont(font);
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setVisible(true);
//        rangeAxis.setRange(minRange, maxRange);
//        rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(2));
        rangeAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
        rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(1);

        final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.2f));
        renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(1, Boolean.TRUE);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, circle);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(1, circle);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(2, circle);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(3, circle);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(4, circle);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(5, circle);
//        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new CustomLabelGenerator());
        renderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(-5);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#4E7AD3"));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.decode("#DC3912"));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2, Color.decode("#FF9900"));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(3, Color.decode("#109618"));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(4, Color.decode("#990099"));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(5, Color.decode("#0099C6"));
//        renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(font);

//        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.WHITE);

        try {
            BufferedImage bi;

            bi = chart.createBufferedImage(300, 100);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
//            rangeAxis.setRangeWithMargins(min(min), max(max));
            String rootpath = this.getRootPath();
            String imagePath = rootpath + TEMP_FILE_PATH + File.separator + "HighLightGraph_" + 1 + ".png";
            System.out.println("=========imagePath============"+imagePath);
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(imagePath), chart, 500, 300);
//            this.recordImageData("highlightChart" + "-" + "1", org.apache.catalina.util.Base64.encode(byteArray));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line:

`plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0,0,0,0));`

to your code after

`final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();`

[image]

[Link to JFreeChart Java Doc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#setAxisOffset%28org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets%29)

Comment: Thankyou it works.... And another one, the axis is in the front of the point, is any other option to get the axis line to the back of the point?

Comment: @Hariprasath Do you mean that the axis is plotted on top of the circle or that the circle is clipped off? You may be better asking new question.